# Retrieve list of Files Matching a Pattern Regardless of Case - R

Tags: r, string, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I am trying to loop through and read some excel files based on a string pattern in the file. I want to read every file containing "feb" in the file name. However, the capitalization of the "Feb" is not always consistent ("FEB", "Feb", "feb", etc.). If I use this code below, it reads all the files with "Feb", but skips the capitalized "FEB" files, or lowercase "feb" files.

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "Feb")
```

Is there a way I can tell R to ignore case and just look for the "feb" string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can set`ignore.case` to `TRUE` (by default it is `FALSE`)

```
list.files(pattern = "Feb", ignore.case = TRUE)
```

Comment: Wow that was easy. Thanks